# Spring Roo 2.0.0.M2 Issue pizzashop sample issue 1 - tailor activate --name web-simple

Tags: java, spring-roo

First thanks for this great project! Success!
I used the 2.0.0.M1 successfully for a real project.

Downloaded the new 2.0.0.M2 project and ran the pizzashop.roo sample for the samples directory.

```
tailor activate --name web-simple
// Create a new project
project setup --topLevelPackage com.springsource.pizzashop --projectName pizzashop
```

This will give:

```
D:\Source\Test\Pizza
λ \Tools\spring-roo-2.0.0.M2\bin\roo.bat
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    2.0.0.M2 [rev 003b42c]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
Spring Roo Eastern Grey UI started at 'http://localhost:9191/'
roo> script --file PizzaProject.roo
tailor activate --name web-simple
Command 'tailor activate --name web-simple' not found (for assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER) Searching 'tailor activate' on installed repositories
0 matches found with 'tailor activate' on installed repositories
Script required 0.031 seconds to execute
Script execution aborted
roo>
```

Comment: I was going to tell you to create an issue in Github, but it seem the Spring Roo project does not have the "Issues" tab (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo)

Comment: I was reading up on Spring Roo and it seems as though it isn't really going anywhere anymore.  I seems to have died.  The support isn't there and it is rarely updated.

Comment: @Dale, You're wrong (see last commits:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/commits/master). There is no Issue tab because this project still using Spring Jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I'm wrong.  I possibly was looking at the old version.  Spring Roo is a great project.

Answer (score 0):

Tailor add-on currently hasn't been migrated to master version and [has been excluded from M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/blob/master/pom.xml#L56).

So, this script should be updated.

Can you create a issue on [project Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/)? Also, Pull request are welcome ;-).

Thank you.

Comment: I'll be glad to create a new Jira ticket, however I do think that ticket [link]https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3752 handles this. i'll put a comment refering to this issues is well.